# Inserting ties in Chinese documents

Tags: formatting, line-breaking, languages, chinese, ctex

I've been following Knuth's advice in the TeXbook about inserting ties (i.e. non-breaking spaces) between words and formulas in appropriate places. However, when I typeset a Chinese document (using CTeX) and inserted ties at the what-I-thought-to-be appropriate places, the line-breaking algorithm did some questionable things, like breaking the word 因为 ("because"). I assume that this is because I've inserted too many ties, making the document hard to line-break. So, what are some general rules for inserting ties between words and formulas in Chinese documents?

Answer (score 1):

As a native Mandarin user, I don't think we keep characters of a single word in the same line. (The only rule that is widely applied is that punctuations cannot appear at the beginning of a line.) I believe it's because

- each character is one syllable so there's little chance you would mispronounce something due to line break (cf. weird hyphenation in English), and
- the characters are monospaced (basically square), so it's aesthetically pleasing to typeset it to be roughly aligned on both sides.
  The only exception would be when typesetting a long title, where line break in the middle of a word would be avoided.

I'm not really familiar with typesetting Mandarin with LaTeX, but even if each word should be kept on the same line, it should be taken care of by LaTeX, not by the user. I believe that in general if you're using a lot of non-breakable space you're doing something wrong.

For reference I think [this page](https://www.w3.org/TR/clreq/) gives a very detailed instruction to typesetting Mandarin if you're interested.

Comment: *I believe that in general if you're using a lot of non-breakable space you're doing something wrong.* Without ties, formulas can appear at the start of lines, which is generally bad, regardless of language.

Comment: I meant within a normal sentence, since from what I understand they're manually marking every word as a non-breakable part.

Comment: I meant inserting ties between words and formulas (not within words).

Answer (score 0):

I’m not familiar with CTeX’s adjustments, if any, to the line-breaking algorithm, and I don’t know Mandarin.  But my understanding is that it would be extremely difficult to identify all word boundaries in Mandarin, so I’d be surprised if your software did.

Some tips that might help:

- The `microtype` package on LuaLaTeX allows for font expansion, reducing the need for line breaks.
- Adding `\emergencystretch=3em` tells the line-breaking algorithm to add large amounts of space between words before it resorts to splitting them, without adding excessive space to paragraphs that looked good already.
- If there’s a better place nearby to break the line, you can add a `\linebreak` command there. You could also give it a parameter from 0 to 4, such as `\linebreak[1]`, where a value less than 4 makes the break optional.  That is, `\linebreak[1]因为` is likely to put the break before the word instead of in the middle.
- You could write `因{\nolinebreak}为` if you really wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

If a proper typesetting engine/support package has been used, the default punctuation penalty should be applied. The W3C Requirements for Chinese Text Layout is a requirement for typesetting engine for things that should be automated (and a guide on how to configure the features provided by typesetting engine) rather than requirements to editors and authors.

Other than that, only important names with special meaning should be taken into consideration for non breakable, this is more of a choice determined by political influence, rather than a common practice of typesetting atheistic.

For scientific writing, the only place that needs extra attention is if mixing digits with units in Chinese, the space between them should be non breakable.

Breaking math equations is whole another issue and, many doesn’t consider math at start of a line a problem: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/200139/math-symbols-at-line-begin